# ffmpeg command line for converting flv to mp3 using vbr @128

Tags: ffmpeg

I have extensively searched google and red through the FFmpeg documentation was hoping some one with a bit more experience could help.

Comment: Have you tried to call ffmpeg? Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 3):

I think you havn't googled hard enough:

- [Encoding VBR (Variable Bit Rate) mp3 audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio)
- [Tip: Encoding VBR (Variable Bit Rate) mp3 audio](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=41)

Following the first example, you could simply do:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -q:a 5 out.mp3
```

Comment: Oh well I just necroposted. Those resources may not have been there a year ago.

Comment: what does -q:a 5 mean here?

Comment: @ikel Refer to the table behind the first link. A quality factor of 5 will produce an average bitrate around 130 kbit/s.